# When trying to add two floats together I get a "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'list'"?

Tags: python, typeerror

One of the floats comes from a list, but it isn't a list. When I print the type it says it's a float.

```
content_based_predictions = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict())                        
for user_id, recipe_id, _ in users_recipes.itertuples(name='predictions', index=False):
    rating_est = 0.0
    counter = 0
    for ingredient_id in recipes_dict[recipe_id]:
        foo = ingredients_dict[user_id][ingredient_id]
        #print("rating_est_type: ", type(rating_est), "foo_type: ", type(foo))
        rating_est += foo
        counter += 1
    content_based_predictions[user_id][recipe_id] = rating_est/counter
```

I then get out this:

```
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-19b066c094f1> in <module>
          6         foo = ingredients_dict[user_id][ingredient_id]
          7         #print("rating_est_type: ", type(rating_est), "foo_type: ", type(foo))
    ----> 8         rating_est += foo
          9         counter += 1
         10     content_based_predictions[user_id][recipe_id] = rating_est/counter
        
        TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'list'
```

If I uncomment the print line i get out:

```
rating_est_type:  <class 'float'> foo_type:  <class 'float'>
rating_est_type:  <class 'float'> foo_type:  <class 'float'>
rating_est_type:  <class 'float'> foo_type:  <class 'float'>
etc.
```

Comment: Are you sure it says that foo is a float in the last line before the error?

Comment: Yes. If I print it, it's a float. If i try foo[0] i get the opposite typeerror:
 ----> 9         rating_est += foo[0]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This isn't possible. Please provide a [mcve] that we can copy and execute.

Comment: I think your list has a mix of floats and lists. It works until you get to the list.

Comment: And `foo[0]` fails for all the floats of course.